# Are the [containers] and [pots] tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) is well established and documented. There is also a tag [pots](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pots), which doesn't seem to differ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Pots is already a synonym of containers so it only looks like it is a separate tag.
I don't think there is any way to show all the synonyms that exist in tags so it is hard to tell

Comment: There is a way to see all synonyms:  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms